# AngularJS Post data to ASP.NET WebForms

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs, web, webforms

I am attempting to post some simple data to a aspx page. I am new to AngularJS and was curious to know if this is possible. below is the .JS but I cannot seem to retrieve the data in the code behind. What is the syntax to retrieve post data within a web forms page?

```
   $scope.TestPost = function () {
        $http({
            url: "index.aspx",
            type: "POST",
            data: { test: 'Tom' },


        }).success(function (data) { alert(data) });

    };
```

here is my server side code. The request returns null

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          string s=  Request.Form["test"];
        }
```

Comment: Look at the HTTP request in your browser's networking tools. What's the status code for the response?

Answer (score 1):

Normally, you can retrieve it from the **Form**.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string test = Request.Form["test"];
}
```

Comment: I did try that, but it came back empty each time. Here is what I used.

  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          string s=  Request.Form["test"];
        }

Comment: Could you show me the fiddler session that angularjs is posted?